# Search through HashMap with user input string

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, user-input

I am creating a dictionary application for a small assignment, these were, unfortunately, given out by random and I have simply pulled one that I have no idea how to implement.

I would like to hear your suggestions for taking user input and using that to look through the HashMap (is this possible?) to provide a definition.

Additionally (sorry), it has to be bilingual, could I simply have all the words in both languages in one HashMap and have a way to search through both?

I am really out of my league here, any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.*;



public class Dictionary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String s1 = getInput("Enter a word to define: ");



        map.put ("Abduction","A carrying away of a person against his will or illegally.");

        map.put ("Ache","To be in pain or distress.");

        map.put ("Befriend","To be a friend to, especially when in need.");

        map.put ("Bilingual","Speaking two languages.");

        map.put ("Comical","Something funny.");

        map.put ("Comprehensive","Large in scope or content.");

        map.put ("Deplete","To reduce or lessen, as by use, exhaustion or waste.");

        map.put ("Detest","To dislike or hate with intensity.");


    }


        private static String getInput(String prompt) {
            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.print(prompt);
            System.out.flush();

            try {
                return stdin.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "Error: " + e.getMessage();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You see `map.put()`... have you tried `map.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've entirely missed the point of a `HashMap` if you're attempting to search through it. A `HashMap` is designed to subvert the need to search, by using the value as the `key`.

```
if(map.containsKey(userInput))
{
    return map.get(userInput);
}
```

This is what is meant by `HashMap` having an `O(1)` complexity when searching. You only ever need to iterate or recurse once.

> Additionally (sorry), it has to be bilingual, could I simply have all the words in both languages in one HashMap and have a way to search through both?

Yes. Just add new entries to the `HashMap`.

```
map.put("Hello", "A greeting");
map.put("Hola", "Una greetingo"); // Forgive my slightly racist Spanish.
```

**Extra (In your case Necessary) Reading**

- Read up on the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). You need to learn some basic stuff about the object. You're out of your depth because you haven't spent the appropriate time learning about the problem.

Comment: Or a Map of Maps (e.g. keyed with "en" and "es"). Or indeed prefixing the keys with the "locale".

Comment: Possibly, but I think just adding everything into one map keeps your code nice and clean. The user might not enter `"Hola", "es"`.